# iOS 8 UITextView not sliding when keyboard shows

Tags: keyboard, ios8, uitextview

In order to avoid the keyboard from hiding the text, I am using the following code, which works just fine in the previous versions of iOS. With iOS 8 nothing happens.

```
- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView*)textView {        
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];

    CGRect frame = self.view.bounds;
    frame.size.height = frame.size.height - [Application keyboardHeight];
    noteView.frame = frame;
    [UIView commitAnimations];

    return YES;
}


- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.1];

    noteView.frame = self.view.bounds;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Maybe I'm missing something silly, but I don't understand what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

I approach this in a different way and it appears to be working well in iOS8.  This example will see the the UITextView take up the available space

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    //Do other stuff

    // listen for keyboard
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                     selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) 
                         name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification 
                       object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                    selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) 
                        name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification 
                      object:nil];
}
```

And then the 2 methods to handle showing and hiding the keyboard

```
- (void) keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *) notification {

    CGSize keyboardSize = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
    CGSize size = self.view.frame.size;

    if (orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown ) 
        textView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width , size.height - keyboardSize.height + 50) ;
    else    
        textView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width , size.height - keyboardSize.width + 50) ;
}

- (void) keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *) notification {
    #pragma unused(notification) 

    textView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width , self.view.frame.size.height) ;
}
```

Not sure if this is the answer but posted as answer so code is formatted.  Hope it helps all the same.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your [Application keyboardHeight] returns, but I just had a similar issue and I figured out what the problem is. When using the same notification method @RobCroll uses, you had to use the keyboardSize.width for landscape orientations in iOS7 and earlier. But in iOS8, Apple finally fixed this bug and you have to use keyboardSize.height for landscape as well! Perhaps your [Application keyboardHeight] also still uses the keyboardSize.width?